# CSV Module Always Needs FilePath? Automation?

Tags: python, csv

Why does this open the file, read it, close it without error. The error being 'filename' does not exist. How are you supposed to eliminate the need to enter a filepath every time you use the csv module? Is there no way to have a script loop through a directory for csv files without requiring a filepath?

```
 data = open(filename, "r")
 d = data.readlines()
 data.close()
```

But not this.

```
import csv

os.makedirs('filesplit', exist_ok=True)

for csvfilename in os.listdir('.'):
  if csvfilename.endswith('.csv'):
     continue

csv_contents = []
csvfileobj = open (filename, 'r')
```

Comment: ...what? If you need to access a file, then you need to know its path. Regardless of whether it's a csv file or not. Could you edit your question to include what you're trying to accomplish? Maybe then we can help.

Comment: Do you know that indentation matters in Python ? Do you understand what continue means ? Why do you complain about the csv module when you don't even use it ? And btw, the error you get has nothing to do with all of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the nature of file objects in Python, one must always specify the path. However, the path is just a string, so you could always write a script to find all files in the current directory (using the `os` module), filter the ones with a `.csv` extension and put them in a list. Here's an example:

```
from os import listdir
import csv

# Get the list of all files/directories in current path
all_files = listdir('.')

# Filter out only the .csv files
csv_files = [file for file in all_files if file.endswith('.csv')]

print csv_files

# Create file objects and csv objects for each CSV
file_objects = [open(file) for file in csv_files]
csv_readers = [csv.reader(csvfile) for csvfile in file_objects]

# Do what you need to do with the data

# Close file objects
for file in file_objects:
    file.close()
```